# wpf resources: resourcedictionary together with xmlDataProvider

Tags: wpf, resources

I'm having problems of using two different kinds of resources definitions in the resources section of a XAML file:

This throws an error:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Maschinen">
        <x:XData xmlns="">
            <machines>
                <machine name="alte Maschine"/>
                <machine name="neue Maschine"/>
            </machines>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyRed.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and this also:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Maschinen">
        <x:XData xmlns="">
            <machines>
                <machine name="alte Maschine"/>
                <machine name="neue Maschine"/>
            </machines>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyRed.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to avoid error messages?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. The error message is as follows:
All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.

Comment: the upper one should work, no? At least I have siomilar constructs in my xaml and never got problem.

Comment: both are running into the same error. None of them works.
If I'm adding a key to the dictionary then it works:
`<ResourceDictionary x:Key="ResDict01" Source="ShinyRed.xaml"/>`
But then I don't know how to access the ResourceDictionary the styles in the ResourceDictionary do not work any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object placed into a `ResourceDictionary` must be assigned a key. This key is used by WPF to retrieve the object, either implicitly (e.g. via default style) or explicitly (e.g. via `StaticResource`, `DynamicResource`).

In your example above, you have created a `ResourceDictionary` without a key, hence the error. The syntax you are looking for is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary> <!-- Create a resource dictionary here -->
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Maschinen"> <!-- Put this into the dictionary -->
            <x:XData xmlns="">
                <machines>
                    <machine name="alte Maschine"/>
                    <machine name="neue Maschine"/>
                </machines>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> <!-- Merge into this dictionary another dictionary ... -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyRed.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Keep in mind the first `ResourceDictionary` tag in the snippet above is implicit if you leave it out. As a result, in your original examples, the tag `<ResourceDictionary>` on its own defines a new second dictionary (without a key) to be added to the outer dictionary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @manton, please mark as answer by checking the V on the top-left corner of the post (see example: http://i.imgur.com/imbXp.png)